# client-go dynamic patch can not remove nodeSelector labels?

Tags: kubernetes, client-go

client-go version: v0.15.10

Can not remove lebels from Deployment nodeSelector when the PatchType is MergePatchType or StrategicMergePatchType?

Here is original yaml file 'test1.yaml':

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta2
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: frontgateway
  name: frontgateway
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: frontgateway
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: frontgateway
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        CLUSTER: WX
        GROUP: IAD
```

patch code:

```
playLoadBytes,_ :=json.Marshal(unstructuredObj)
_,err=DynamicClient.Resource(mapping.Resource).Namespace(namespace).Patch(name,types.StrategicMergePatchType,playLoadBytes,metav1.PatchOptions{})
```

patch yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta2
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: frontgateway
  name: frontgateway
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: frontgateway
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: frontgateway
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        GROUP: IAD
```

When I remove the line "CLUSTER: WX" from test1.yaml and execute patch() method,  deployment resource still has the "  CLUSTER: WX"  label, but add a new label could work.

I saw the official document https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/update-api-object-kubectl-patch/,  it says `Notice that the tolerations list in the PodSpec was replaced, not merged. This is because the Tolerations field of PodSpec does not have a patchStrategy key in its field tag. So the strategic merge patch uses the default patch strategy, which is replace.`

So I check the field tag of NodeSelector in Kubernetes source code,:

```
NodeSelector map[string]string `json:"nodeSelector,omitempty" protobuf:"bytes,7,rep,name=nodeSelector"`
```

There is no "patchStrategy" tag, so why the patch() doesn't do the replace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Notice that the tolerations **list** in the PodSpec was replaced, not merged

The replace strategy applies to lists, and nodeSelector is not a list.

```
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      tolerations:
      - effect: NoSchedule     <- list
        key: disktype
        value: ssd
```

---

```
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: frontgateway
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: frontgateway
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        CLUSTER: WX        <- not a list
        GROUP: IAD
```

Replace for lists is used because order of a list can get easly messed up and it's hard to predict to which element of a list you are refering to. This is why it's easier to replace the whole list.

In case of objects that you can address every element directly and clearly, it's not necessary to replace anything.

Comment: Thanks. So how can I patch the nodeSelector labels ?Is the problem still caused by PatchType

Comment: Looking at your patch yaml, probably using Update method would work better than  Patch

Comment: If using Update, I have to provide resourceVersion, and actually the yaml file contains Service definition, so I have to provide the clusterIP which I couldn't know.

Comment: This: `kubectl patch deployments <deploymentname> --type='json' -p='[{"op": "remove", "path": "/spec/template/spec/nodeSelector/CLUSTER"}]'` removes CLUSTER key. Now all you need to do is to apply this patch in code.

Comment: That would be this part: `[{"op": "remove", "path": "/spec/template/spec/nodeSelector/CLUSTER"}]`. Use it as your patch and let me know if this solves it. Also, accept/upvote if you find my answer helful.

Comment: In this way, I need to know what has been modified in advance, but in fact, I don't pay attention to what has been modified in yaml. Maybe the next modification is not nodeselector. I just need to trigger resource update when modifying

Comment: Would functionality simmilar to `kubectl apply` solve your problem? There is [fourth PatchType](https://godoc.org/k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/types#PatchType) beside these 3 you mentioned: `type.ApplyPatchType` which allows for server-side apply, and was introduced in k8s v1.16. Check out [this blog post](https://ymmt2005.hatenablog.com/entry/2020/04/14/An_example_of_using_dynamic_client_of_k8s.io/client-go#Using-the-dynamic-client-to-implement-SSA) for example code